# How do computers generate random numbers?

Tags: python, random-number-generator

How does a computer generate 'random' numbers?

How close to truly 'random' can a number generated by a computer actually be?

Is there software / programming language out that that might generate a more 'truly random' number than others?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9

Comment: This question seems borderline off-topic. The second part for sure, is far better suited for StackOverflow than SuperUser.

Comment: As was commented below, this question [How are pseudorandom and truly random numbers different and why does it matter?](http://superuser.com/q/712551/820) answers the randomness question very completely.

Answer (score 4):

Many common implementations of random number generators, are not truly random.  Computers typically utilize [Pseudorandom Number Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), which means the computer uses a defined algorithm to generate a sequence of numbers that appear to be random.

In Python you can use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module to generate pseudorandom numbers.  However, if you look at the docs, they include this note:

> Warning The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used
>   for security purposes. Use [os.urandom()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom) or [SystemRandom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) if you require
>   a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: @duDE, only half of the question is off-topic.  I think the other half is completely on-topic and an interesting question.

Comment: Related SU question: [How are pseudorandom and truly random numbers different and why does it matter?](http://superuser.com/questions/712551/how-are-pseudorandom-and-truly-random-numbers-different-and-why-does-it-matter?rq=1)