# How can I view how much lag / CPU time a Google Chrome extension adds when loading a page?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, performance, google-chrome-extensions, latency

For example, I would like to know how much lag / CPU time the Google Chrome extension [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?hl=en-US) adds when loading the webpage [How are pseudorandom and truly random numbers different and why does it matter?](https://superuser.com/q/712551/116475).

If the solution is dependent on the operating system, I use Windows 7 Ultimate, 10 Pro and 11 Pro.

Comment: The chrome developer tools should show the page load time. Try loading the page with and without the extension enabled.

Comment: Or if you're desperate use some screen recorder software which is pretty much built into every Windows OS and graphics card package these days. Load the page once to cache the resources and enable the addon, start the recording, then reload the page. Disable the addon and reload again. Stop the recording and launch your favourite video editor and look at the times it takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize the answers the question received in the comment section. Use Chrome developer tools or some screen recorder software to do a time comparison with and without the extension enabled.

---

Comments:

> - The chrome developer tools should show the page load time. Try loading the page with and without the extension enabled.  [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)**♦**
>    [May 21 at 7:25](https://superuser.com/questions/1722136/how-can-i-view-how-much-lag-cpu-time-a-google-chrome-extension-adds-when-loadi#comment2659458_1722136)
> - Or if you're desperate use some screen recorder software which is pretty much built into every Windows OS and graphics card package these days. Load the page once to cache the resources and enable the addon, start the recording, then reload the page. Disable the addon and reload again. Stop the recording and launch your favourite video editor and look at the times it takes. [Mokubai](https://superuser.com/users/19943/mokubai)**♦** [May 21 at 8:35](https://superuser.com/questions/1722136/how-can-i-view-how-much-lag-cpu-time-a-google-chrome-extension-adds-when-loadi#comment2659475_1722136)